# How can I get my sidebar to float right?

Tags: html, css, css-float, sidebar, floating

So this is driving me insane. I have been trying for the past two days to get my sidebar to float right, but it just keeps showing up at the bottom of the page! It may be that the answer is quite simple, but I can't seem to figure it out on my own... maybe one of you can help me!

```css
#wrap { 
 width: 1200px;
 /*margin: 0 auto;*/
 background-color:#e6fdff;
 color:#185358;
 padding:0;
}
#content {
 float:left;
 clear:right;
 padding:50px;
 padding-bottom:80px;
 /*margin:0 auto;*/
 right:250px;
}
#sidebar {
 float:right;
 width:300px;
}
#sidebar ul {
 list-style:none;
}
#sidebar ul a {
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:'Crushed', cursive;
 color:#4B3C27;
}
#footer {
 width:100%;
 height:60px;
 position:fixed;
 bottom:0;
 left:0;
 border:1px solid #4B323F;
 border-width:1px 0;
 background-color:#E6FDFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
   <!--<div style="clear:both;"></div>-->
   <div id="content">
    <h2>Welcome to The Life of Esther!</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. 
                </p>
    <div id="sidebar"> 
     <ul>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
      <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div> <!--end sidebar div-->
   </div> <!--end content div-->
   <div id="footer"></div> <!--end footer div-->
  </div> <!--end wrap div-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to take `sidebar` out of the `content` div and modify some styles. See the updated code here at http://jsfiddle.net/w8gek7u8/

And see the code below:

```
<style>
    #wrap { 
        width: 1200px;
        /*margin: 0 auto;*/
        background-color:#e6fdff;
        color:#185358;
        padding:0;
    }
    #content {
        float:left;
        clear:right;
        padding:50px;
        padding-bottom:80px;
        width:900px;
    }
    #sidebar {
        float:right;
        width:150px;
    }
    #sidebar ul {
        list-style:none;
    }
    #sidebar ul a {
        text-decoration:none;
        font-family:'Crushed', cursive;
        color:#4B3C27;
    }
    #footer {
        width:100%;
        height:60px;
        position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        border:1px solid #4B323F;
        border-width:1px 0;
        background-color:#E6FDFF;
    }
    <style>
```

and HTML as

```
<div id="wrap">
            <!--<div style="clear:both;"></div>-->
            <div id="content">
                <h2>Welcome to The Life of Esther!</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 

Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. 
                </p>
                            </div> <!--end content div-->

    <div id="sidebar"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!--end sidebar div-->

            <div id="footer"></div> <!--end footer div-->
        </div> <!--end wrap div-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the #sidebar outside of the #content , and add `width:800px` for #content.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your html to:

```
<div id="content">
                <div id="main-content"> 
                    <h2>Welcome to The Life of Esther!</h2>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 

    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. 

    Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. 

    Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 

    Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis. 
                    </p>
                    </div>
                <div id="sidebar"> 
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="blog1.html">Blog1</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div> <!--end sidebar div-->
            </div>
```

And then I changed the css to:

```
#sidebar {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#main-content {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You have to play a little bit with the right and top attributes. Also you must set a width of the main-content role.